# how to fire a button action method in didselectrowatindexpath in iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview with custom tableview cell. in the tableview cell there are two labels and one button.what I want it to fire the button action for user selected row to hide a label in the same row.

this is my controller for table view

**ViweController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablev;

    @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellFocusStyleCustom;

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger sec = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger rw = indexPath.row;

    TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    cell.numberlabel.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"selected section :%li ---> selected row :%li",(long)sec, (long)rw);



    //in here I want fire the button acction in the cell for each row when cell tap.(not when the button click in the cell).
}
```

**TestTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *staticlabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberlabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *hidebutton;

@end
```

**TestTableViewCell.m**
//I have tried to implement button click method here.It worked.but at that point it didn't recognised which cell is taped.

**NOTE : I have tried to implement button click method here.I worked.but at that point it didn't recognised which cell is taped. **

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement by two way one you can add Button Action in to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and setting tag of Button like following code:

```
hidebutton.tag=indexPath.row;

[hidebutton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(hideaction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Its Action Method is**

```
-(IBAction)hideaction:(UIButton*)sender
{
  NSIndexPath *hideIndexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
  TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *)[self.tablev cellForRowAtIndexPath:hideIndexpath];

}
```

Another way is you can achieve this same from DidSelect method with following code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *)[self.tablev cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//use your cell object for hide anyting 
    }
```

Comment: nice and thank you very much.I tried different ways, didn't success. this is great.

Comment: you can do by also diff way @bhavin's answe also right you can do it by this too

Answer (score 1):

You can get `indexPath.row` of `UITableView` in button action:

---

Make action of button in `yourviewcontroller.h` file:

```
- (IBAction) My_button:(id)sender;
```

---

In `yourviewcontroller.m` file:

```
- (IBAction)My_button:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                           toView:self.tbl_view];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tbl_view indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

---

And If you want to do this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` then you don't need to dequeue cell again.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section);

    TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.numberlabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the correct cell first , You can achieve it by replacing

```
TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
```

by this:

```
 TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Your method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger sec = indexPath.section;
NSInteger rw = indexPath.row;

TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.numberlabel.hidden = YES;
NSLog(@"selected section :%li ---> selected row :%li",(long)sec, (long)rw);



//in here I want fire the button acction in the cell for each row when cell tap.(not when the button click in the cell).
}
```

Hope this Helps!